# Why does this array, which is not empty, return as empty?

Tags: javascript

Really struggling to understand why my conditions are resolving that the array is empty when it isn't!

Here is the code:

```
const info = [
    [
        {
            "Post": 7
        }
    ]
]

let Result;
     if (!Array.isArray(info[0][0]) || info[0][0].length === 0) {
        Result = {"Error": "No info"}
     }
```

Even though `info` has data in it, I still get back `Result` as `{"Error: "No info"}`.

Why are my `if` conditions not working properly? I think its something to do with the `!Array.isArray(info[0][0])` part but not sure exactly what.

UPDATE:

If there is no `Post` then `info` becomes just this:

`const info = [ [  ] ]`

Thats why I need to check whether `info[0][0]` is empty or not

Comment: the first answer is right also there is no sense in info[0][0].length

Comment: The first condition is True (not an array but an Object), the second is False (But it's not taken into account here), so Result is still undefined. You can check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pn3vax?file=index.js It's working well I think. Did you miss some part of your code hat could change that perhaps ?

Comment: @QuentinGrisel thanks. please check my update for what happens when theres no `Post`

Comment: @volumeone Ok but I still don't understand where is the problem. `!Array.isArray(info[0][0]) === true` implicitly mean there is something inside your `info`. You stick to this I think

Comment: @QuentinGrisel it is undefined in your code because you used `result` instead of `Result` in the `console.log()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a bug when you call `Array.isArray`. You gave the input `info[0][0]`, but you want to check if `Array[0]` is an array.

New code with fixed bug:

```
const info = [
    [
        {
            "Post": 7
        }
    ]
]

let Result;
     if (!Array.isArray(info[0]) || info[0].length === 0) {
        Result = {"Error": "No info"}
     }
```

Edit: Also removed extra `[0]` when checking length.

Comment: thank you. can you please see my update... how can I test for when the second array contains something and for when it doesnt?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't already do that? If it checks the length of the array to be zero it should work, right? Another way of checking it could be `typeof info[0][0] == "object"`

Comment: if an array contains an array then its not empty right? Wouldnt `Array.isArray[0]` be true for `[ [ ] ]` ?

Comment: Well, you're right that checking `Array.isArray(info)` would be true if info was `[ [ ] ]`. I was talking about when doing 'info[0].length === 0'. Since `info[0]` would be `[]`, `info[0]` would have a length of zero. Does it still not work after testing it?

Comment: Yep it works. To get `Post` I have to do `info[0][0].Post`.... so to check if it was empty or not I was doing `info[0][0].length` which of course is wrong because that is checking the object's length inside the nested array when one didnt exist. Mind just went to jelly

Answer (score 0):

Array.isArray returns false because info[0][0] is { "Post": 7 }